# Flutter multiple TextFormFields in Material App - Reset text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have multiple TextFormFields in a stateful widget. When i scroll down to the bottom and then if i scrolled to top, the text i typed in the first TextFormFields get reset. 
It seems Flutter dispose the widget when the widget is out of the current view, so i tried with UniqueKey(), but still no success. What am i missing?

```
 body: ListView(
    key: UniqueKey(),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    children: <Widget>[
      TextField(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34, letterSpacing: 8),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 50),
      TextField(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34, letterSpacing: 8),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 50),
      TextField(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34, letterSpacing: 8),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 50),
      TextField(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34, letterSpacing: 8),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 50),
      TextField(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34, letterSpacing: 8),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 50),
      TextField(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34, letterSpacing: 8),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 50),
      TextField(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34, letterSpacing: 8),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 50),
      TextField(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34, letterSpacing: 8),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 50),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Can you try [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create global variable of  `TextEditingController()` and set it to your `TextFormField()`

You can get data from that object:

`var username = usernameController.text`

```
var usernameController = TextEditingController();
var passwordController = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
         TextFormField(
            controller: usernameController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34, letterSpacing: 8),
         ),
         TextFormField(
            controller: passwordController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34, letterSpacing: 8),
         ),
   ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a TextEditingController to your TextField

```
TextField(
   key: UniqueKey(),
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 34, letterSpacing: 8),
   controller: TextEditingController(),
),
```